# Use Yahoo Pipes to replace redirect links to resultant ones in an rss feed

Tags: rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

I am wondering whether what I want can be acheived by using Yahoo pipes (which I haven't used before). I subscribe to many feeds using Google Reader. I mainly use a news reader for Android called Newsrob and when I see an article I am interested in, I add it to Pinboard or other bookmarking service. Unfortunately many feeds use Feedburner or other service that means that all links in the rss feeds are not the correct ones. They are redirect urls so that they can track click throughs.
Take the Lifehacker feed: http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/vip
The first link is http://feeds.gawker.com/~r/lifehacker/vip/~3/RYy7Dk9oE2Q/stolencamerafinder-locates-your-stolen-camera-by-using-your-existing-photos
This redirects to:
http://lifehacker.com/#!5796912/stolencamerafinder-locates-your-stolen-camera-by-using-your-existing-photos
I want to bookmark the resultant link.
Is there a way of using Yahoo pipes to create a custom rss feed with the correct links? It would need to detect that the link uses a 301 redirect and replace with the correct link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pipe that does exactly what you want, replacing any links that are 301 redirects with the actual link:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=26d9b7a2d3a81ae496fbff5f9b53171a

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for. This is going to really help with booking marking straight from my feed reader. Just one point, is it possible to get it to use the same feed title as the feed it reads? Not a major issue but when I add the feed to my reader it is entitled "RSS resolve 301 links copy". Anyway, thanks so much!

Comment: I did not see a way to do this within Pipes, but most feed readers have the ability to rename a feed. e.g. in Google Reader you can click the options arrow at the right of the feed and choose "Rename Subscription". In most desktop readers you can right-mouse click the feed and choose either "Rename" or "FeedProperties".

Comment: I've added the feed to Feedburner and used their rename feeds option. The other annoyance which this Pipe doesn't address is the Google Analytics query strings that some feeds add. I wrote a php script that strips these characters. Basically you create the feed in your pipe, add it to my script and then add to Feedburner. A bit long winded, but it works. Thanks again for all your help!